# Keep optimal width of an element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make sure a HTML element (in this case an input box) maintains the 'optimal' width on different screen resolutions.

My *subjective* rules (for simplicity: ignoring the need for margins):

1. Initially set the width of the element to 40% of the window width
2. If the size of the element drops below a certain width (eg. 200 pixels), keep that minimum width
3. If the element won't fit on screen (in this example: window width is smaller then 200 pixels), set the width of the element to the window width

Can this be achieved using pure CSS (and still support IE8)?

Comment: Yes. Look up media queries.

Comment: In answer to your question - yes.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I still need to support IE8

Comment: read this http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you can use media queries, here is a working example for your requirements.

```
input {
  width:40%;
  min-width:200px;
}
@media (max-width: 200px) {
  input {
    width:100%;
    min-width: 0;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bEvUZ/

Comment: Slightly easier to maintain than koningdavid's answer. As stated by koningdavid, for IE8 support https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js is needed

Answer (score 1):

```
.input_box {
   width: 40%;
}


@media (max-width:500px) { /* 40% of 500px is 200px */
    .input_box {
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:200px) { /* full width when the screen is smaller than 200 px */
    .input_box {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/PXYRN/ and https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ for IE8 Support

Comment: Yes +1, thank you this works, however Magnus' answer is slightly easier, thanks to the min-width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

There are multiple ways to do that.

You can use media queries, flexboxes, and also play with box-sizing.

In your case, media queries are exactly what you need.
It's called "Responsive design".

Ex :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .bloc {
    width : 40%;
  }
}
```

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: No, the only way to support IE lower than 9 is to use conditionnal comments or a custom JS library